# How to display database details immediately when user choose any dropdown value in laravel using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I want to display details from the selected dropdown. All the details are from the database. The problem is, the price did not display when user choose 1 dropdown value. Which part did I missed? Here is my code:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/prodview', [OrderController::class, 'prodfunct']);
Route::get('/findPrice', [OrderController::class, 'findPrice']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function prodfunct()
{
    $prod=DB::all();//get data from table
    return view('orders.order',compact('prod'));//sent data to view
}

public function findPrice(Request $request){

    //it will get price if its id match with product id
    $p=DB::select('select price from pastas')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
    
    return response()->json($p);
}
```

**View:**

```
<span>
                            <x-label for="pastaingredient" :value="__('Pasta Ingredient: ')" />
                            <x-input id="pastaingredient" style="font-size:14px;" class="pasta_ingredient" type="text" name="pastaingredient" value="{{ old('pasta_ingredient') }}" disabled />
                        </span>
                        
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function()
                            {
                                $(document).on('change', '.pastas', function() 
                                {
                                    var ingredient = $(this).find("option:selected").data("ingredient");
                                    $('.pasta_ingredient').val(ingredient);
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

Comment: Hi, does `data` giving you correct values ? Do `console.log(data)` inside success function of ajax and see what its showing.

Comment: Also , why not simply do `$('.prod_price').val(data.price);` ?

Comment: @swati here inside my console --> app.js:18406 GET https://homestead.test/findPrice?id=Spicy%20Chicken%20Arrabiata 500

Comment: You have error at your server end .

Comment: @Swati do your know how to handle the error?

Comment: No , I might be completely wrong .. but , here `value="{{ $pizzaitem->name }}"` you have name assign and in your backend you are comparing that with `id` ?

Comment: this one --> value="{{ $pizzaitem->name }}" for validation purpose, when user did not complete the form, it will get the old selected dropdown value, right now, i want to display the details, if user choose the dropdown menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232199/discussion-between-adda-and-swati).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way to achieve this would be storing price value as `data-attribute` and then whenever user select any value from select-box you can simply use `$(this).find("option:selected").data("price")` to get value from options .

So , you just need to add `data-price="{{ $pizzaitem->price }}"` to your options i.e :

```
<option @if(old('pastas') == $pizzaitem->name) selected @endif value="{{ $pizzaitem->name }}" data-price="{{ $pizzaitem->price }}">{{ $pizzaitem->name }}</option>
```

Then , your ***jquery*** code will be like below :

```
$(document).on('change', '.pastas', function() {
var price = $(this).find("option:selected").data("price");
$('.prod_price').val(price);
});
```

Comment: but how to make it stay in the text box when user did not complete the form and accidentally click on the submit button, the validation happends right

Comment: <x-input id="pastaingredient" style="font-size:14px;" class="pasta_ingredient" type="text" name="pastaingredient" value="{{ old('pasta_ingredient') }}" disabled />

didnt work...

Comment: which input box is that ? Also , what does `{{ old('pasta_ingredient') }}` has ?

Comment: pasta ingredient will put inside this input box. i thought it will call the ID, and its not work.

Comment: I am not getting is this related to your current question  or its some other problem ?

Comment: yes! same question. how to get the old input text for pasta ingredient?

Comment: i.e : for price ? and for select its showing correct old  values ? If yes on load you can call `$(".pastas").trigger("change")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232267/discussion-between-adda-and-swati).

Answer (score 0):

The function  `var a=$(this).parent();` return the immediate parent of `this`. In this case, `a` is this div:

```
<div>
            <x-label for="pastas" :value="__('Choose pastas:')" />
                        <select name="pastas" id="pastas" class="pastas">
                            <option @if(!old('pastas')) selected @endif disabled>Please choose</option>
                                @foreach ($pastainfo as $pizzaitem)
                                    <option @if(old('pastas') == $pizzaitem->name) selected @endif value="{{ $pizzaitem->name }}">{{ $pizzaitem->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                        </select>
      </div>
```

so that at this line `a.find('.prod_price').val(data.price);`  JQuery only find `prod_price` in the `a` div and can not see it there leading this error.

Comment: okay I see, then what actually I need to change? I'm so lost, doing this codes for 3 days LOL

Comment: Please mark this answer as useful if it helps you fix this bug and I know it is the right solution.

Comment: I dont understand, which part should I change @Freeman?

Comment: Replace this line: a.find('.prod_price').val(data.price) by this line :  $('.prod_price').val(data.price);

Comment: I already edit my question coding. it did not show the price....

Comment: Is there any element having CSS class 'prod_price'  in your page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232200/discussion-between-freeman-and-adda).